# Dependency ignored because of conflict Android studio

Tags: android, gradle, google-drive-android-api

I'm trying to add the following dependency but it is ignore. I can't understand how to resolve it please help me Thank you.

Dependency

```
 compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev170-1.20.0'
```

> Waring for ignoring dependency
>       Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version
>   provided by Android.
>            In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages Warning:Dependency
>   org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for release as
>   it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
>            In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can exclude dependencies in the build.gradle file of your module.

```
compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev170-1.20.0') {
    exclude module: 'httpclient' //by artifact name
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' //by group
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient' //by both name and group
}
```

Comment: Are there any risks to excluding these dependencies? Google Drive will now be using a newer version of httpclient from apache.

Answer (score 28):

Exclude module httpclient from all configurations. Add this code in the build.gradle file:

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpclient"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Only this working for my case. `compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev170-1.20.0') {
    exclude module: 'httpclient' //by artifact name
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' //by group
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient' //by both name and group
}` is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code to exclude the conflicting modules from the google APIs library.

```
 compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev170-1.20.0' {
    exclude module: 'httpcore'
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain this answer and why it should work (as opposed to the original code)?