# Gradle Compile: How to identify group and module from dependency?

Tags: gradle, module

Some times, I don't want to add all of the dependency, so I need to exclude some from dependency, for example :

```
  compile('com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.20.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }
```

I found com.google.http-client source code in github [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client), however, from the source code I can't find which part belongs to group "**org.apache.httpcomponents**" and which part belongs to '**httpclient**'

I am a beginer on Gradle, so Can anyone explain how do I identify **group** and **module**?

(like stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30460148/dependency-ignored-because-of-conflict-android-studio), someone just post **exclude group '****',module:'****'**, but I want to know where is the group and module,so in the future I can solve this qustion by myself.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not about exclusion of some classes or packages from dependency, rather about exclusion of some transitive dependencies. Group and module are properties for looking up libraries within maven repositories. For your dependency

```
com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.20.0
```

Group is `com.google.http-client`, module is `google-http-client` and the version is `1.20.0`. And when you add

```
exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
```

You just exclude sone transitive dependency to be loaded and added to your project by default.

In your exact case, you can take a look at the project's [pom-file](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client/blob/dev/pom.xml), which declares project dependencies as follows:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>${project.httpclient.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Here, `group` is equals to `groupId` and `module` is equals to `artifactId`. You can read about it [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html).

If you wish to find out, what transitive dependencies are in your project, you can take a look at the library description page at the [repository web page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.http-client/google-http-client/1.20.0), or just call in command line `gradle dependencies` to print out all the dependencies of your project, include transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use [grepcode](http://grepcode.com). So, for your example, you can browse the dependencies of `'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.20.0'` at http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.http-client/google-http-client/1.20.0/.