# Gradle Android "Duplicate class foo found in module bar" error

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-module

I have android module named A. I added dependency to another module B like so: `implementation project(':B')`. While the module A builds without an issue, when I try to build (and run) integration tests, I get

```
Duplicate class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser found in modules kxml2-2.3.0.jar (net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0) and xpp3-1.1.3.3.jar (xpp3:xpp3:1.1.3.3)
Duplicate class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException found in modules kxml2-2.3.0.jar (net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0) and xpp3-1.1.3.3.jar (xpp3:xpp3:1.1.3.3)
Duplicate class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory found in modules kxml2-2.3.0.jar (net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0) and xpp3-1.1.3.3.jar (xpp3:xpp3:1.1.3.3)
Duplicate class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer found in modules kxml2-2.3.0.jar (net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0) and xpp3-1.1.3.3.jar (xpp3:xpp3:1.1.3.3)
```

I tried to exclude `org.xmlpull.kxml` by changing my import statement to

```
    implementation (project(':B')) {
        exclude group: 'org.xmlpull.v1'
    }
```

but the problem still exists. I have run out of ideas. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case the solution was to exclude xpp3

`implementation(':B') {
        exclude module: 'xpp3'
    }`

[here is a nice explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42827160/12013241)