# Android Cloud vision

Tags: android, google-cloud-vision

I'm getting this error when building my android project in android studio

```
    Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
```

Here is a link to the repo I am using: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-vision/tree/master/android/CloudVision

Cheers

Comment: Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30460148/dependency-ignored-because-of-conflict-android-studio

Comment: Actually after I did that it threw a whole bunch of errors back at me.