# Android Studio reporting a dependency conflict for org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient that I can't find

Tags: android, apache, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I recently added

`compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev76-1.22.0`

to my project, and now I'm getting:

**"/my/project/path/app/build.gradle**

**WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages"**

But I can't find any reference to that anywhere in the project, much less in any gradle configuration file.

Is that probably a result of some other library I'm using? And if so, how do I figure out which one and/or work around it if there's no indication in the warning *where* the problem actually is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's because `google-api-services-drive` indirectly depends on `httpclient` (`google-api-services-drive` needs `google-api-client`, which needs `google-http-client-jackson2` and `google-oauth-client`, which both need `google-http-client`, which needs `httpclient`).

There are instructions for viewing the dependency tree on another question: [Using gradle to find dependency tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-dependency-tree)

Comment: Thanks!

And to deal with the warning:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30460148/dependency-ignored-because-of-conflict-android-studio/30460255